# MIME Headers Not Making it Through Gmail API

Tags: python, mime, gmail-api

I'm trying to automate the creation of drafts via the Gmail API, and I want these drafts to be responses to existing emails. To do this, I believe I need to set the "threadId" header (Gmail specific), the "References" header, and the "In-Reply-To" header. Additionally, for Gmail to consider the message to be a reply, the "Subject" header must match the original email.

I'm hardcoding all of these headers into a MIMEText object, and then base-64 encoding (urlsafe) the message as a string and having the Gmail API deliver it. However, the "threadId", "In-Reply-To", and "References" headers don't appear to ever make it in the email that's sent, as they don't exist in the MIME shown when clicking "Show original" in the Gmail UI.

```
new = MIMEText("reply body text")
new["In-Reply-To"] = "[Message-ID of email to reply to]" #looks like <..@mail.gmail.com>
new["References"] = "[Message-ID of email to reply to]" #looks like <..@mail.gmail.com>
new["threadId"] = "[threadId of message to reply to]" #looks like 14ec476abbce3421
new["Subject"] = "Testsend2"
new["To"] = "[Email to send to]"
new["From"] = "[Email to send from]"

messageToDraft = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(new.as_string())}
message = {'message': messageToDraft}
draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId="me", body=message).execute()
```

Comment: The `threadId` should not be sent as part of the `raw` key, for it to work it has to be separate.So `message` should contain {`raw`: my_raw, `threadId`: my_thread_id}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, it's a lot simpler than that! If you just supply the correct Subject in the headers, and the correct threadId in the body, Google will calculate all the references for you.

```
new = MIMEText("This is the placeholder draft message text.")
new["Subject"] = "Example Mail"
new["To"] = "emtholin@gmail.com"
new["From"] = "emtholin@gmail.com"

raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(new.as_string())
message = {'message': {'raw': raw, 'threadId': "14ec598be7f25362"}}
draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId="me", body=message).execute()
```

This results in a draft, ready to be sent in the correct thread:

[image]

Then, I send the mail. As you can see, the references are calculated for you:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.28.130.132 with HTTP; Sat, 25 Jul 2015 07:54:12 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <CADsZLRz5jWF5h=6Cs1F45QQOiFuqNGmMeb6St5e-tOj3stCNiA@mail.gmail.com>
References: <CADsZLRwmDZ_L5_zWqE8qOgoKuvRiRTWUopqssn4+XYGM_SKrfg@mail.gmail.com>
    <CADsZLRz5jWF5h=6Cs1F45QQOiFuqNGmMeb6St5e-tOj3stCNiA@mail.gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 16:54:12 +0200
Delivered-To: emtholin@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CADsZLRxuyFhuGNPwjRrfFVQ0_2MxO=_jstjmsBGmAiwMEvfWSg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Example Mail
From: Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>
To: Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

This is the placeholder draft message text.
```

Comment: Very good solution, thank you. I later realized that something similar to this was possible, although I prefer your solution: Gmail will calculate and append the necessary headers if you generate a draft with the same recipient and with "Re:" prepended to the subject.

Comment: @monstermac77 No problem! :) Cool! Good to know.

Comment: @Tholle Any idea how to do the same thing within Google Apps Script? It seems to ignore the threadID in:"message": { "raw": rawEncoded, "threadId": threadId}

Comment: @Layla I have never used Apps Script, sadly. Maybe this documented [reply function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replybody) could give some clues?

Comment: This creates a draft reply but it differs from when I create one manually. When I do it manually in Gmail: click reply then start typing a message then navigate away and return back to the email you can see the email draft still there at the bottom of the original email. This doesn't happen when I use the API.

Comment: @Tholle this created draft doesnt attach the conversation and when I hit send button, it sends as a new email not a conversational email. Any ideas, how to include previous email too ?

Comment: For anyone else who might be confused, the `message_id` that you have to include when creating the reply email is NOT `message['id']`, but instead (and quite confusingly IMHO) it's `header['value']`, where `header` is the unique header in `message['headers']` whose `header['name']` is 'Message-ID'.

And the two are very much not the same. Oops

Answer (score 1):

if you want to not only create the draft but also additionally send it then extension of above code (one additional line after draft =...create().execute():

```
    draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId="me", body= message).execute()
    message = service.users().drafts().send(userId='me', body={'id': draft['id']}).execute()
```