# How to reply to threadId using Gmail api in node js?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

Here I want to send a reply using Gmail API.
For that, I got a successful response while retrieving.
Now I have threadId
using that threadId I need to send a reply instead of creating a new thread

This is my response for retrieval of mail

```
{
  id: '178fe5f9cc632096',
  threadId: '178fe5f9cc632096',
  labelIds: [ 'IMPORTANT', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX' ],
  snippet: 'it&#39;s working --',
  payload: {
    partId: '',
    mimeType: 'multipart/alternative',
    filename: '',
    headers: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    body: { size: 0 },
    parts: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  sizeEstimate: 5218,
  historyId: '119777',
  internalDate: '1619175369000'
}
```

And my code for sending reply

```
function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    var str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message
    ].join('');

    var encodedMail = Buffer.from(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
    return encodedMail
}
function sendMessage(auth) {
                    try {
                        var raw = makeBody('abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'test subject', 'workinggggggg...');
                        const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
                        gmail.users.messages.send({
                            auth: auth,
                            userId: 'me',
                            resource: {
                                raw: raw,
                                message_id: res.data.threadId
                            }
                        }, function (err, response) {
                            if (err) {
                                return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                            }
                            else
                                console.log(response)
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                }
```

But while using this code a new thread is creating.
Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages):

> If you're trying to send a reply and want the email to thread, make sure that:

> The Subject headers match
> The References and In-Reply-To headers follow the RFC 2822 standard.

**Thus, proving `'test subject'` as the subject will not work if this is not the  real subject of the email to which you want to reply.**

Also:

**As you can draw the the [Resource: Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message), you should pass the thread id to the parameter `threadId`.** `message_id` is not a valid parameter.

Comment: But in my headers, I don't have references and In-Reply-to headers

Comment: If you don't have any, then you do no need to worry about this part. But the other two points (matching subject and correct assignation of `threadId`) are crucial.

Comment: Yeah I have changed the threadId assignment and the subject was changed to Re:`${subject}`..But still a new mail is sending instead of replying to existing thread

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589476/how-to-send-a-reply-with-gmail-api) helps you. Do you have the thread view activated in your Gmail UI?

Comment: Hi, now I'm able to send a reply but the receiver is getting new mail instead of a reply to previous and from the sender side I'm getting another mail to that same thread instead of reply

Comment: Is the receiver a Gmail user? Does he have conversion view enabled?

Comment: yes he is a Gmail user and enabled he's conversation

Comment: The References and In-Reply-To headers will form only when a reply is sent right? So here I'm sending the reply but that thread doesn't have the References and In-Reply-To headers.

Comment: The `In-Reply-To` should go into the email header and contain the message id to which you want to reply - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880439/trying-to-reply-to-an-existing-email-with-gmail-api).

Comment: Yeah, I have used the Message-Id value as In-Reply-to's value, replies are sending fine. How can I dynamically update the token file? Now I'm doing it manually.

Comment: I am glad it works now. As for the token - that is already a differerent quesiton, but in short: You need to create a flow with an OAuth2 client , prompting for authorization and generation of a refresh and access token - just like in the sample of the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_set_up_the_sample).

Comment: No, not that one, we need another file as token.json in which we have an access token and refresh token and that file has expiry. so how can I refresh it

Comment: The refresh token automatically creates a new access token whenever the latter expires. But for this you need to incorporate the workflow as mentioned in the quickstart. Unless you have a different implementation - see [google-auth-library-nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs). I suggest you to write a separate post where you explain your situation and use case more in detail. This will make it for users easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to keep Message-Id as In-Reply-To and References
You need to update the In-Reply-To and References values like below

```
function makeBody(ref, InReply, to, from, subject, message) {
    var str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
        "References:", ref, "\n" +
        "In-Reply-To: ", InReply, "\n" +
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message
    ].join('');

    var encodedMail = Buffer.from(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
    return encodedMail
}

const headers = res.data.payload.headers
                        let subject
                        let to
                        let ref
                        let InReply
                        headers.forEach(element => {
                            if (element.name === 'Subject' || element.name === 'subject') {
                                subject = element.value
                            }
                            if (element.name === 'From' || element.name === 'from') {
                                to = element.value
                            }
                            if (element.name === 'Message-ID' || element.name === 'Message-Id') {
                                ref = element.value
                                InReply = element.value
                            }
                        });
  var raw = makeBody(ref, InReply, to, 'example1@gmail.com', subject, 'reply message text');
```