# Send Reply to email thread using Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail-api, reply

I am trying to reply to an email I sent to myself, the subject of the email is "Testing Function"
I have a function subject() which returns subject, message_id, and thread_id below
('Testing Function',
'DEFxmu7HPSRAti50ki2i6PK_DOOPLwMm5fiR+_dPkcOR7mep7hQ@mail.gmail.com',
 '166e2507fc661924')

My full code is:

```
def create_message(sender, to, message_id, thread_id, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['from'] = sender
    message['to'] = to
    message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id
    message['References'] = message_id
    message['threadId'] = thread_id
    message['subject'] = subject

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId="me", 
    body=message).execute())
    print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message

def send_email(orders):
    SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
    credentials = auth.get_user_oauth2_credentials(scopes=SCOPES, 
                                                   client_id='xxxxx', 
                                                   client_secret='xxxxxx')
    service = discovery.build('gmail','v1', credentials=credentials)
    message_text = orders[0]
    created_message = create_message('th14@gmail.com','th14@gmail.com', 
        subject()[1],subject()[2], subject()[0], message_text)
    send_message(service, 'me', created_message)

send_email(['Msg Received'])
```

It sends the email but not to the desired thread, just sends a new email.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `threadId` to the return of your `create_message` function.

```py
return {
    'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode(),
    'threadId':thread_id
}
```

Also, remove `message['threadId'] = thread_id`

```py
def create_message(sender, to, message_id, thread_id, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['from'] = sender
    message['to'] = to
    message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id
    message['References'] = message_id
    message['subject'] = subject

    return {
        'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode(),
        'threadId':thread_id
    }
```

Now just call `send_message` passing message create from the function above:
Assuming `subject()[1] = "$your_thread_id"`

```py
SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
credentials = auth.get_user_oauth2_credentials(scopes=SCOPES, 
                                                   client_id='xxxxx', 
                                                   client_secret='xxxxxx')
service = discovery.build('gmail','v1', credentials=credentials)
message_text = orders[0]
created_message = create_message('th14@gmail.com','th14@gmail.com', 
    subject()[1],subject()[2], subject()[0], message_text)
send_message(service, 'me', created_message)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

A small addition for anyone else who might be confused, the `message_id` that you have to include when creating the reply email is NOT `message['id']`, but instead (and quite confusingly IMHO) it's `header['value']`, where `header` is the unique header in `message['headers']` whose `header['name']` is 'Message-ID'.

And the two are very much not the same. Oops

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads#adding_drafts_and_messages_to_threads), you can add a message to a thread as part of [inserting](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) or [sending](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) a message.

> In order to be part of a thread, a message or draft must meet the following criteria:

> 1. The requested `threadId` must be specified on the `Message` or `Draft.Message` you supply with your request.
>    2. The `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers must be set in compliance with the [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#appendix-A.2) standard.
>    3. The `Subject` headers must match.

Check this link for additional reference: [How To Send A Reply With Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589476/how-to-send-a-reply-with-gmail-api)