# Gmail API: Search for an existing thread with the subject line and if it exists reply to the thread, otherwise send a fresh email in python

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use gmail api to reply to existing thread (if it exists) or otherwise start a new email thread.

Here is what I found:

```
x = gmailClient.service.users().threads().list(userId='me',q='from:noreply-dv360@google.com subject:"Report #234354 : "Reporting" from Sneha"').execute().get('threads', [])
```

but this returns me a list of array which look like this:

```
{'id': '177ed7354840ddae1', 'snippet': '-- <b>Report</b> Name: <b>Reporting</b> Account: DBM (21324356) <b>Report</b> ID: <b>34565</b> File Name: Reporting_1234354', 'historyId': '232456'}
```

I want to reply to the given thread... So here's my two major questions:

1. How to fetch the thread Id of a thread by it's subject line?
2. How to reply to a thread by it's thread id?

**Edit 1:**

```
def send_email(self,sender, to, subject, message_text, cc = None,messageType = "plain"):

        queryParam = f'from: me subject: "{subject}"'

        message = MIMEText(message_text,messageType)
        message['to'] = to
        message['from'] = sender
        message['subject'] = subject

        if cc != None:
            message['cc'] = cc
        
        emailBody = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(message.as_string(),"utf-8")).decode("utf-8")}

        threadSearch = self.service.users().threads().list(userId='me',q=queryParam, maxResults = 1).execute().get('threads', [])

        if len(threadSearch):
            threadSearch = threadSearch[0]
            emailBody["threadId"] = threadSearch["id"]
            messageId = self.getMessageIdFromThread(threadSearch)
            emailBody['subject'] = subject
            emailBody["Reference"] = messageId
            emailBody["In-Reply-To"] = messageId
            print("Response: ")
            response = self.service.users().messages().send(userId = 'me', body = emailBody).execute()
        else:
            response = self.service.users().messages().send(userId = 'me', body = emailBody).execute()
        return response


    def getMessageIdFromThread(self, thread):

        tdata = self.service.users().threads().get(userId="me", id=thread['id']).execute()
        msg = tdata['messages'][0]['payload']

        for eachMsg in msg['headers']:
            if eachMsg['name'] == "Message-Id":
                return eachMsg["value"]
        
        return False
```

Here are the changes I did... Now This is what I get:

From Sender Side:

[image]

At Receiver End:

[image]

For some reason, the threading doesn't happen to the reciever end. Can someone guide me where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/53149409/1841839

Comment: Checked it out, but still stuck at the same point. Have added some more code for more clarification

Comment: Where are you stuck? The post contains multiple questions.

Comment: In the Edit 1: As I have provided, I am able to send to the thread, but it appears as a new email at receiver side. Whereas appear to be thread in sender side.

Comment: Have you tried to send it to other emails or have you checked that the emails are displayed separated on the receivers end but are on the same thread? Can you update on it?

Comment: I didn't exactly get you when you said `have you checked that the emails are displayed separated on the receivers end but are on the same thread`. I am sending the email on the same threadId, so they're on the same thread but are sent in new thread only at reciever end.

Comment: Have you checked that the mail you are sending complies with [Adding drafts and messages to threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads#adding_drafts_and_messages_to_threads)