# Threading Email Messages with Gmail Api [After New Threading Requirements]

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

I am creating Message Object with raw(base64 encoded) & threadID field values. By using a valid threadId (of an existing email) , i was able to create a Threaded Message in users inbox.

**After the 'Threading Changes' changed by google in April 2019, the messages are not threading. Instead they appear as individual messages, despite the ThreadID of both messages being same.**

Google has recommended to add 'References' & 'In-Reply-To' header with value of 'Message-Id' from existing email. The Problem is, whenever we sent a new email using gmail api, we only receive message snipped back which only has ThreadID and Label values. To Retrieve 'Message-Id' of this sent email, another GET API call needs to be made. This is adding extra load to the system and un-necessarily making the system complex.

My Questions:

1. **Is there any other way to Thread Messages using Gmail-APi?**
2. **Can we retrieve Message-ID without making another API Call?**
3. **Can we use any other headers /custom headers to establish a relationship between messages for them to thread.**

Answer (score -1):

### When you send an email with Gmail API, the response contains the message id, as you can confirm with the [Users.messages: send Try this API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9buJI.png), so another API call is not necessary.

[image]

Comment: the value contained in id is same as ThreadId and not Message_ID.Here is an example of one such response {
 "id": "14fd1c555a1352b7",
 "threadId": "14fd1c52911f0f64",
 "labelIds": [
  "SENT",
  "INBOX",
  "IMPORTANT",
  "UNREAD"
 ]}  .  As you can see its just a threadID and not message-id. Threading Policy requires that you have to put value of Message-ID in references and in-reply-to header .@ziganotschka

Comment: `14fd1c555a1352b7` is not the same as `14fd1c52911f0f64` , it is the message Id by which you can rtrieve a message with the Gmail API. But I see, you mean the Id that is contained in the headers and needs to be attached to 'In-Reply-To'. This data has to be retrieved indeed through a GET request as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32591614/11599789

Comment: However, the information in the documentaiton is slightly confusing. It says that "The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard" - if they are provided. However, if you do not provide this information, but only the threadId - the message will still be threaded correctly.

Comment: Yes the emails used to thread only by passing the thread id in message object , but after Google has introduced new Threading Changes in April 2019, the same has stopped working. Now as per Google Policy it requires to add In-Reply-To and References Header

Comment: I did not try it in Java, but with the Try this API it still works with the Thread Id only

Comment: I used the same Try It Explorer and the Messages are not threaded. I sent from gsuite email to another gmail account , the mails did not thread.

Comment: If you are having same sender and recipient, it appears as a thread. but not when sent to different recipients

Comment: Then I would not know another workaround then retrieving the headers with a GET request

Comment: message id in the response is NOT same as the Message-ID in the header. The Message-ID in the header is what is required as the 'In-Reply-To' header's value