# How to send an existing email to a new thread using gmail API

Tags: python, email, flask, gmail, gmail-api

**I'm attempting to send an existing email to another thread using the gmail API in Flask.**

**Context:**
I've created a new message object and successfully made the `In-Reply-To`, `References` and `threadId` equal the `message_id` and `thread_id` respectively. (Following [Gmail's API reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send))

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, thread_id, message_id, message_text, service):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  if type(message_text) != str:
    message_text = str(message_text)

  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id
  message['References'] = message_id
  message['threadId'] = thread_id
  print('created message threadId: %s does == ..' %message['threadId'])
  print(thread_id)

  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  raw = raw.decode()
  body = {'raw': raw}

  messages = service.users().messages()
  send = messages.send(userId='me', body=body).execute()
```

**Problem:**
I'm able to successfully send the new messages to my inbox but they are created with a new `threadId` even though the print statement in the above code shows the same `threadId`.

Then, when I follow the code example [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626069/mime-headers-not-making-it-through-gmail-api):

```
  body = {'message': {'raw': raw, 'threadId': thread_id}}
```

I get the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required">
```

**Question:**
How can I generate these emails so they thread with the same `threadId`?

**Note:** I have found similar questions [here for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589476/how-to-send-a-reply-with-gmail-api/32591614#32591614), and [here for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792616/threading-email-messages-with-gmail-api-after-new-threading-requirements) but haven't found an answer for python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be gathered from the information in the links you provided, you do not need to provide the `In-Reply-To` and `References` to enable threading, providing the `threadId` in the request body and make the `Subject` within the raw message body match, as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) is enough.

Please perform the following modification:

Remove the line `message['threadId'] = thread_id` - the threadId belongs into the request body, not the message body

Sample:

```py
def create_message(sender, to, subject, thread_id, message_text, service):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  if type(message_text) != str:
    message_text = str(message_text)

  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  raw = raw.decode()
  body = {'raw': raw, 'threadId':thread_id}
  messages = service.users().messages()
  send = messages.send(userId='me', body=body).execute()
```

Comment: In the documentation link you provided it says at the bottom that: "1. The requested `threadId` must be specified on the `Message` or `Draft.Message` you supply with your request.
2. The `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard." ie with the same `message_id`

Comment: In reply to modification 1: I did attempt to remove this and add it to the request body as described in the question, however the HTTP error isn't originating from the `as_bytes()` method outlined in your 2nd modification. I should have mentioned that in python 3, the `as_bytes()` method is needed, as discussed here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/93

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send specifies that `threadId` is an optional property that does not go inside of the row message body - i.e. it doe snot need to be encoded. You can test it yourself with the corresponding "Try this API" method of the documentation. The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard - if they are set at all, but they do not need to be set.

Comment: I updated my code according to the python 3 requirements, it should work for you now and thread correctly.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka, the "Try this API" section helped me better understand the format of the HTTP request.

Comment: Glad to hear this!