# Sending a reply with Gmail API Python

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I created two Gmail accounts and I'm trying to create an e-mail thread between them with the Python Gmail API.

I can send e-mails without any issue, but when it comes to replying to each other and creating a thread, it is simply not working : the new message is successfully displaying as the answer of the received email for the sender, but it is appearing as a new message - without a linked thread - for the receiver.

This problem was described here in 2019 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186609/21966625

However, the Gmail APIs changed a lot since this article and I didn't find how to use these advices with today's API.

I tried to carefully respect the instructions of the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending?hl=fr) by defining the message's parameters `References` and `In-Reply-To` as the received message's id when replying.

Indeed, I retrieve the email :

```
received_email= service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=label['id']).execute()
```

I get a dict looking like:

```
{'id': '189462395f418017', 'threadId': '189462395f418017', 'labelIds': ['UNREAD','INBOX'], 'snippet': 'xxx'....}
```

Hence, when I'm building my e-mail, the following method should work :

```
message_id=received_email['id']

message = EmailMessage()
message.set_content('')
message['To'] = 'john.doe@gmail.com'
message['From'] = 'john.doe@gmail.com'
message['References'] = message_id
message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id
message['Subject'] = 'Automated draft'
```

In the same way, I defined the `threadId` as the id of the message I wanted to reply to.

```
create_message = {'raw': encoded_message,
                  'threadId': message_id
                 }
send_message = (service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
```

Thanks to this part of the code, the answers are correctly displayed (for the sender of the answer) as explained above, but it appears as a new message - unlinked to a thread - for the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found why my method did not work ; even if the dict mention a kind of message id :

```
email = {'id': '189462395f418017', 'threadId': '189462395f418017', 'labelIds': ['UNREAD','INBOX'], 'snippet': 'xxx'....}
```

I thought the `messageID`could be taken just by call `email['id']`.

The real `messageID` is somewhere in the `['payload']['headers']` dictionnary ; one could find it by a loop like :

```
 for p in email['payload']['headers']:
                    if p['name']=='Message-ID' :
                        message_id=p['value']
```

This way we have the true `messageID` of the email, and the threads are successfully created.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send the reply message as part of a thread. You'll need to identify the thread ID from the original message, not the message ID, and add that as part of the new message's message object...

```
create_message = {
    'raw': encoded_message,
    'threadId': threadId
}
```

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message

You may also need to include the headers "References" and "In-Reply-To" with the message ID of the [last message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589476/how-to-send-a-reply-with-gmail-api?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yes, indeed, I did it too, but the `id` and the `threadId` are actually the same keys. As you can see, I hence added it with the same dict as yours to the new message ; the `References` and `In-Reply-To` are also set to the messageID as described in the docs

Comment: ```id``` and ```threadId``` are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

You are on the right track using the message's parameters `References` and `In-Reply-To` on your reply body but the issue lies on the `messageId` and `threadId` that you have obtained from your previous request.

You can alternatively use the code below that ensures you obtain the `threadId` of the thread that you want.

You just need to specify the `subject` of the thread that you want to reply to. The code below behaves as follows:

1. List the threads on your inbox and collect all thread id using `users.threads.list`
2. Extract the thread id that matches the `subject` of the thread that you want to reply
3. Retrieve the thread details and extract necessary metadata for the reply using `users.threads.get`
4. Send the reply to the thread using `users.messages.send`

### Code:

```
"""Authorization and Authentication of Account to Access GMAIL API """
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from email.message import EmailMessage
import base64

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

"""Authorization and Authentication of Account to Access GMAIL API """

# Set up the Gmail API client
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# Specify the subject to match
subject = 'Sample email thread'

# Retrieve the list of threads
threads = service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute().get('threads', [])

# Find the thread with the matching subject
matching_thread = None
for thread in threads:
    thread_id = thread['id']
    thread_details = service.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=thread_id).execute()
    message = thread_details['messages'][0]  # Get the first message in the thread
    message_subject = next((header['value'] for header in message['payload']['headers'] if header['name'] == 'Subject'), None)
    if message_subject == subject:
        matching_thread = thread
        break

if matching_thread:
    thread_id = matching_thread['id']
else:
    print("No matching thread found.")

# Retrieve the details of the thread
thread = service.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=thread_id).execute()
messages = thread['messages'][0]['payload']['headers']

# Retrieve the metadata of the thread
for (k) in messages:
    if k['name'] == 'To':
        recipient = k['value']
    if k['name'] == 'Subject':
        email_subject = k['value']
    if k['name'] == 'From':
        sender = k['value']
    if k['name'] == 'Message-ID':
        message_id = k['value']

# Constructing the reply message
message = EmailMessage()
message.set_content('This is a sample reply')
message['To'] = recipient
message['From'] = sender
message['Subject'] = email_subject
message['References '] = message_id
message['In-Reply-To '] = message_id

encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()

create_message = {'raw': encoded_message,
                  'threadId': thread_id}
# Sending the reply message to the thread
send_message = (service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
```

Note: My code on authorization and authentication part may differ from yours

### Sample Thread

[image]

### Reply using the code:

[image]

### References:

[Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides)

[Users.Threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads)

[Method: users.threads.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/list)

[Method: users.threads.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/get)

[Method: users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)

Comment: My mistake relied on believing `messageID` was simply the id of the email. With choosing the thread by looking for a specific subject, the algo could answer to the wrong thread if they have the same subject. Plus I don't think this is allowed with Gmail API, but a user can change the subject in the middle of a thread when using the web interface.