# gmail api adding label id and thread id while sending as reply (send mail with same thread id while reply)

Tags: laravel-4, gmail-api

I'm trying to send mail using gmail api using laravel.

my sent msg is

```
$text = 'From: '.$from.'
To: '.$to.'
Subject:'.$subject.'

'.$body.'';

$encoded_message = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($text), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$message->setRaw($encoded_message);
$message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
```

I tried to edit label id and thread id as follows,

```
$text = 'labelIds: ':'.SENT.'
'From: '.$from.'
To: '.$to.'
Subject:'.$subject.'

'.$body.'';
```

which gives syntax error. How to add labelid and thread id for gmail-api?

**edit1**

my message after sending is,

```
object(Google_Service_Gmail_Message)#1048 (14){  
  [  
  "historyId"
 ]   => string(4) "4171"   [  
  "id"
]   => string(16) "15270b9c7b867bab"   [  
  "internalDate"
]   => string(13) "1453590169000"   [  
  "labelIds"
]   => NULL
```

It's `creating a new threadId`, where i need to `sent it as reply`. How can i `send the mail with same threadId`?

Comment: Doesn't the message get the `SENT`-label when you send it?

Comment: it's giving null as in the edit

Comment: and also. the sent item is empty in the gmail, since the labelid is missing. The message is showing only while clicking ALL MAIL, not the SENT

Comment: I do not know laravel-4 but did you try `$message->setThreadId(id from original mail);`? Also you do not need to send a label with the reply. Gmail API will automatically set SENT label on it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved this by now, but I had similar issues and found this thread while looking for a solution, so I wanted to share the approach I used in case someone else needs it.

Based on Gmail's API specification

> 1.The requested threadId must be specified on the Message or Draft.Message you supply with your request. 
>   2.The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard.
>   3.The Subject headers must match.

The number 2 complicated things for me, because I tried to set the References and In-Reply-To headers manually. My idea was to get them from the last message in the same thread, but the API didn't return those headers and what I set was apparently inaccurate. Then, following this thread [MIME Headers Not Making it Through Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626069/mime-headers-not-making-it-through-gmail-api), I removed all additional headers and set only the threadId and a matching subject.

I used [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library for formatting the mime string, instead of doing it manually (it decreases the possibility of mistakes). With composer, you just need to add "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2" in the require section of your composer.json. 
Here's my solution:

```
$thread = $gmail->users_threads->get($user_id,$threadId);
if($thread) {
    $opt_param['threadId'] = $threadId;
    $thread_messages = $thread->getMessages($opt_param);
    if($thread_messages) {
        $messageId = $thread_messages[0]->getId();
        $messageDetails = $gmail->users_messages->get($messageId);
        // get the subject here from the headers of $messageDetails. You will use it below as $subject.
    }
}

$message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'YOUR_EMAIL'; // I tried with 'me' here, but PHPMailer doesn't consider it valid, so it can either be the email or userId 
$mail->FromName = 'YOUR_NAME';
$mail->addAddress('RECIPIENT_EMAIL'); // Make sure this is the same as the email in the message you reply to
$mail->Subject = $subject; // the subject from $messageDetails from above
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->preSend();
$mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();

$raw = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($mime), '+/', '-_'), '='); // web safe base64 encode
$message->setRaw($raw); // You set the thread id to your message object now, separately from the other headers
$message->setThreadId($threadId); 

$gmail->users_messages->send($user_id, $message);
```

Variables used above:

```
$gmail - your instance of Google_Service_Gmail;
$user_id - the id of the authenticated user (can be 'me' for the current logged in user);
$threadId - the thread under which you want to send your email
```

Hope this is helpful.