# Obtaining `gmail.compose` privileges for single G Suite email account to send emails via GMail API

Tags: python, gmail, google-oauth

I am trying to compose drafts programmatically via the GMail API, using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts) and the following line of code:

```
service.users().drafts().create(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()
```

but I receive the following error:

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Note that directly sending messages with `gmail.send` privileges does not work for me - I want to [thread messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626069/mime-headers-not-making-it-through-gmail-api).

In the API console, I tried enabling the following scope `../auth/gmail.compose`, but there is a warning message that `Because you've added a sensitive scope, your consent screen requires verification by Google before it's published.`

I have submitted my app for verification, but I just received an email stating that "We've extended the deadline to fully complete your verification from May 15th to June 26th, 2019".

Actually, no users will use my G Suite email accounts (so my app cannot be used to spy on their messages) and I only need access to a *single* email account `info@example.com` to send notifications to users who use my site on `example.com`.

Is there any way to get server-side access to my `info@example.com` account using my password and programmatically draft messages without having to go through the lengthy and unnecessary app verification process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can have an "internal", rather than a client facing "public" app, for which all GMail scopes are automatically available.

Here is the response from the Google team that describes the steps (it worked for me):

> It appears your app is only used by the people in your domain.
>
> If this is correct, please reply to this email to confirm that is the
>   case. We will then reject your request so that you are able to update
>   your project from public to internal.
>
> In addition, you will need to associate your project with your
>   organization by following the steps below:
>
> If you have not already done so, create an Organization by following
>   the [Quickstart Using Organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations) instructions.
>
> Migrate the project into the organization you created as shown in
>   [Migrating Existing Projects into the Organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing). Once you have
>   associated your project with your organization, you and the project
>   users in your organization can use the app to directly access [OAuth
>   scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). No verification will be required.